# For iOS how do I create a draggable button within a button?

Tags: ios, ipad, uibutton, drag

In xCode I'm making an iPad app, and have created a series of counters in UIimageViews that drag around the screen when you touch them. All good so far.

But now I want to have another smaller hidden button just above each counter that is disabled, so that when you tap on the counter the smaller button can appear and can perform an action (such as 'return to starting position' or 'hide'.

I'm just not sure where to go with this one now.  Any ideas or hints would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you create the buttons and set their frames and add them as sub views to your view. From that point on you can hide them by making their alpha = 0.0, have them appear disabled by setting alpha to say 0.5 (set enabled to NO), and make them live with alpha=1.0. You can animate frame and alpha changes. For convenience you can set their tag properties to a value related to the counter so you can easily get them using viewWithTag:.

Comment: OK, cheers for that.  I need to learn more about views and subviews obviously!